# Scaffolding CRUD in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, crud, scaffolding

I'm developing an application on the send zend framework based and I'm missing the Scaffolding. (Something I am used to from other frameworks.)

Is there anything like that for zend framework? I have found `zfdatagrid` but I would like to know if there is a better solution.

Comment: I think I know what you mean but I'm not familiar with the 'scaffolding' term. Does it mean generating fast web tables for db tables?

Comment: @tharkun Yes, about that. An auto-generated web interface for DB tables, from which further functionality can be built.

Comment: As far as I know, and I use Zend Framework a lot, this is one of the bigger shortcomings compared to say Symfony. I really hope someone tells us a different truth here.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this one:

framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Controller_Scaffolding

Comment: I have looked up it before. Zfdatagrid is more developed yet

Comment: 404 page not found